# sql statement : I need sum of all columns based on primary key

Tags: php, mysql

I am very new to mysql. The below table is exactly what I am working upon.I need sum of all columns based on primary key.
I have a table `tbl_datas` with the follwing fields:

```
id  Brand    shops  restaurant
1    8         7      6
1    4         5      8
2    8         7      6
2    7         2      12
```

I need sum of all columns based on primary key.
My Output should be like:

```
id  Brand   shops   restaurant
1    12      12        14
2    15      9         18
```

Comment: What did you try yourself?

Comment: Why this question has been voted negative.?

Comment: "This question does not show any research effort" as the downvote button says. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask I guess you have been downvoted because you didn't show us what you've tried/failed/didn't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(brand), SUM(shops), SUM(restaurant) FROM tbl_datas GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUM(brand) AS Brand, SUM(shops) AS shops, SUM(restaurant) AS restaurant FROM tbl_datas GROUP BY id
```

Note: AS an alias and is optional,But i suggest to use it for clarity

Comment: I don't get the "rest" (just before "FROM"). Is it a typo?

Comment: Sorry @caCtus,It was just a typing mistake.